# add a list to the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Well im doing a application where i have a model like this

```
public class Saldo
{
    public Saldo()
    {
        Expenses = new List<Expese>();
        Incomes = new List<Income>();
    }

    public int SaldoId { get; set; }
    public List<Expense> Despesas { get; set; }
    public List<Income> Rendimentos { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
}
```

what i want to do is add a single expense to the list but it is not working, when i output on the console the count it is always null
in the controller im doing this:

```
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ExpenseId,TipoDespesaId,DespesaDescricao,DespesaValor,TipoPagamentoId,Data,Comentario")] Expense expense)
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var balance = db.Balance.Where(d => d.ApplicationUserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();


            expense.ApplicationUserId = userId;

            if (balance == null)
            {
                Balance s = new Balance();
                s.Expense.Add(expense);
                s.ApplicationUserId = userId;
                db.Balance.Add(s);             
            }
            else
            {
                Balance.Expense.Add(expense);
            }

            db.Expense.Add(expense);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

The expense comes from the form and is passed to the Action

I created a new instance of Balance it worked adding the ApplicationUserId but the expense on the list didnt work, can someone explain me why it happen?

Ps: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What's the "db" variable?  Do you ever tell it to save?

Comment: I edited the question and posted all the code, sorry should posted it previously

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's just lost in the translation, but your model doesn't make sense.  You have a list of Expense called "Despesas" but in the constructor you call it "Expenses"  Whatever that list is called is what you need to add your expense object to.  Instead of

```
s.Expense.Add(expense);
```

it would be

```
s.Despesas.Add(expense);
```

Comment: just lost in the translation, the expense is never added dont know why